# How can I take the schema in Oracle and put it on another Computer?

Tags: database, oracle

I've been working on my Java-Database project on my desktop for days, and now its time to put them on my laptop, the java project won't be a problem, but what about my schema ? my database ? I don't feel like typing it all over, isn't there a way to take it out of Oracle? then put it back on oracle as well on my laptop?

Comment: Try starting [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_database_Backup_and_Recovery_FAQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm#CHDDBGDF%27). Oracle has these two tools called exp and imp for exporting a database and importing one. It will help transfer the database from your desktop to your laptop.

Edit: Even more [info](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ#How_does_one_use_the_import.2Fexport_utilities.3F)