# Oracle: Exporting oracle database to .sql file and import same .sql file in android as SQLite db

Tags: android, oracle, sqlite

I am developing an android application where I need to export oracle database to .sql file (not as .dmp file). And then I will copy that .sql file to android assert folder. Now I will import that .sql file to sqlite db. But, I want to know how to export oracle db to .sql file.

Here I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to export oracle database to .sql file.
2. Is it possible to import the same .sql file from asserts to android SD Card as SQLite db.

Can someone please help me in solving these issues. Is there any tutorials or examples available that would be great help to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should specify the format you want for the .sql file.  You can name any file .sql.  You want a bunch of insert statements?

Comment: Yes, sql file will contain bunch of statements or queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL() package to get your schema from the database that can be run to recreate the db object.  Note not everything can be translated into sqllite depending on how complex your schema is.  [dbms_metadata reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm)  Just spool the content to a file from sqlplus

Answer (score -1):

See here. Oracle has these two tools called exp and imp for exporting a database and importing one. It will help transfer the database.

Edit: Even more info

[How can I take the schema in Oracle and put it on another Computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825756/how-can-i-take-the-schema-in-oracle-and-put-it-on-another-computer/10825817#10825817)

Comment: exp and imp will not create .sql files.

Comment: if exporting oracle database to .sql file is not possible. Then what are possible ways that i can use oracle db in android and create sqlite db in sd card.